# PyQt and Bespin (KDE style)

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, kde4

What tab widget decorate by Bespin Tabs? I tried QTabWidget, QTabBar, KTabWidget, KTabBar, bau no effect. What Im doing wrong?
All KDE apps and SMPlayer decorate by Bespin, but acetoneiso and PyQt apps have regular tabs=(

I mean this Bespin:
http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Bespin?content=63928

Answer (score 0):

That is a bit strange. It should have automatically decorated your application with the style Bespin. However you can force it decorate the application with a specific style.

```
# Check the available styles with qt
sf = QStyleFactory()
print list( sf.keys() )
```

That should list all the style Qt can render. If Bespin is not listed then, there might be a problem with the installation. To force your application to use the Bespin style ( assuming its available ):

```
qApp.setStyle( sf.create( "Bespin" ) )
```

Or say, if you want just one widget to be decorated by Bespin, then, you may do this:

```
w = QWidget()
w.setStyle( sf.create( "Bespin" ) )
```